# JSON data unable to properly serialize in jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json, ashx

I've been playing with the recently released jQueryGannt plugin / application [from here](https://github.com/robicch/jQUeryGantt) and I'm attempting to write a drop down that is populated with the names of the different stored gantt charts on the server. To generate this drop down I use this function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GanttLoader.ashx?action=getGantts",
    context: document.body, 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.gantts != null) {
            for(var gantt in data.gantts) {
                alert(gantt.name + " is locked " + gantt.locked);
                var toAppend = $("<option/>").val(gantt.name).html(gantt.name);
                if(gantt.locked) { toAppend.attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
                $("#saved_gantts").append(toAppend);
            }
            $("#saved_gantts").append($("<option/>").val("add new").html("add new"));
                saved_gantts_loaded = true;
            }
            else if(data.status == "none") {
                $("#saved_gantts").append($("<option/>").val("add new").html("add new"));
            }
        },
        error: function() { alert("couldn't load gantt charts"); }
});
```

At the moment, this is what the server is sending to generate the drop down (no gantt data is being sent yet, just a simple list of what gantts are open and which are currently being edited):

```
{
  "gantts": [
    {
      "name": "other",
      "locked": true
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "locked": true
    }
  ]
}
```

For some reason in the success function's call the for loop loops over both objects stored in the array, but the alert always prints `"undefined is locked undefined"`. Does anybody know what's wrong with my handler or my JSON being returned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `data.gantts[gantt].name` instead of `gantt.name`.

Here is updated code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "GanttLoader.ashx?action=getGantts",
    context: document.body, 
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.gantts != null) {
            var gantts = data.gantts;
            for(var i in gantts) {
                alert(gantts[i].name + " is locked " + gantts[i].locked);
                var toAppend = $("<option/>").val(gantts[i].name).html(gantts[i].name);
                if(gantts[i].locked) { toAppend.attr("disabled", "disabled"); }
                $("#saved_gantts").append(toAppend);
            }
            $("#saved_gantts").append($("<option/>").val("add new").html("add new"));
                saved_gantts_loaded = true;
            }
            else if(data.status == "none") {
                $("#saved_gantts").append($("<option/>").val("add new").html("add new"));
            }
        },
        error: function() { alert("couldn't load gantt charts"); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use

```
for (i=0;i<data.gantts.length;i++) {
    alert(data.gantts[i] + " is locked " + data.gantts[i].locked);
```

I have found the for(... in ...) format to be somewhat unreliable when dealing with certain frameworks